# Menu screen - with just 2 options

Tags: android, menu, google-materials-design

I am developing an android app that has a **menu screen** just after the login. i.e. The menu screen is the 2nd screen in sequence.

The **menu has just 2 options**. I am confused how can I achieve it according to **Google Material** specifications. Should I use **Cards** ? Or any other component ?

I didn't use a slide menu as I just have only 2 options in the menu.

[image: Menu screen]

Comment: Are both options used just as frequently? I wouldn't be surprised if they're not. Consider elevating one option above the other.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is consisting of only 2 menus you should ask yourself whether you need to split them into menus.

Or have your users land on one page and have the other page tabbed.

Hiding content by making menus like this has been shown to reduce engagement.

Answer (score 1):

[image: App Menu Screen with Cards]

**I agree that Cards are the best Material Design pattern for the design flow you have in mind.**

But before you settle on this design flow, I would like to challenge it with some usability questions:

- Are you confident that your users will understand what to expect from the options "Planogram" and "Merchandising Activity" sufficiently to be able to pick the right option?
- Is it **imperative** that the user makes an "either / or"  choice at the outset? Or could you design it in a way that allowed the user to avoid making an up-front choice?

If any of these questions raises a doubt in your mind, I think you should reconsider your current design flow.

Assuming you are confident with the flow, however, I am attaching a wireframe with a couple of suggestions, as follows:

1. Use Cards to present the binary options -- as per your own hunch
2. Add informative text to the cards -- to inform the users what to expect
3. Add a Universal Menu -- at this point, it may only allow the user to log out. But it also serves as an anchor, and on later screens, users may use it to return here.